# What functions does 3dplot support for parametricfill input

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used 3dplot for tikz-pgf to draw an ellipsoid. Now I'd like to color the surface in dependence of it's mean curvature (I have calcuated this function.) But 3dplot does not seem to support sin and cos arguments as it's parameter to the parametric fill option. Is that right? I'm going to provide a testcase here:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{3dplot}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}      %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
                \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{40}{20}%
                {1/sqrt(%
                        sin(\tdplottheta)^2*( (cos(\tdplotphi)/2)^2 + (sin(\tdplotphi)/1)^2 )%
                        + (cos(\tdplottheta)/1)^2
                )}{black}%
                {%
                                sin(\tdplotphi)
                        % 2*(5-3*sin(\tdplottheta)^2*cos(\tdplotphi)^2)/%
                                % sqrt((4-3*sin(\tdplottheta)^2*cos(\tdplotphi)^2)^3)
                }%
                {}%{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
                {}%{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
                {}%{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Would like to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if that feature is not supported. In that case: Do you know a tool I could use to achieve my goal?

Kind regards
Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

I think now, you need to use `\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}` and not `3dplot`. Your example works well for me . Sometimes the viewer is not very happy ...

```
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{40}{0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=1]
      \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
         {1/sqrt(%
        sin(\tdplottheta)^2*( (cos(\tdplotphi)/2)^2 + (sin(\tdplotphi)/1)^2 )%
                + (cos(\tdplottheta)/1)^2)}{black}%
                 {100*abs(2*(5-3*sin(\tdplottheta)^2*cos(\tdplotphi)^2)/%
        sqrt((4-3*sin(\tdplottheta)^2*cos(\tdplotphi)^2)^3))}% 
        {}{}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, 

I'm very happy you anwsered me. But your image is also just "red". The surface is not colored according its mean curvature.

Kind reagards

Comment: @kostja I did not understand the question, sorry . I think you need to use an math expression positive and you need to increase the values. See my new example

Comment: Hey, wow, it works! This is really great!
Thank you very much. Do you know what range it expects the value to be in?

Many greetings
Konstantin

Comment: @kostja: Rather than "answering" your question, you should comment Altermundus' answer (you may have to register to do so), edit your original question or ask a follow-up question.

Comment: kostja,@lockstep: I converted the answer post to a comment now.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you very much!
@lockstep: I'm very sorry. I'm new to stackexchange and have no account yet.

Comment: @kostja I don't read enough the documentation and I need to read the code of the package. You need to works with positive values and I suppose with values between 0 and 100 but i'm not sure. Perhaps the amplitude between lower and higher values must be greater than in your code (It is my intuition makes me write this)